# One ApiController paremeterless constructor error, but another one works perfectly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC and Web Api 2.2 app with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I have this error when I do a POST to `http://myServer/api/Codes`:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'CodesController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor.

I have this packages installed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="DotNetZip" version="1.9.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.13.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.es" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.es" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.es" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.2.2.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Ninject.MVC5" version="3.2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.2.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost" version="3.2.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi" version="3.2.4.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0.6" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

But the strange thing is I have an ApiController that works perfectly, and two ApiControllers that doesn't work.

Working `ApiController` constructor:

```
public ExternalCodesController(
    IGenericRepository<EXTERNAL_CODES> genericRepositoryECodes,
    IGenericRepository<CHINA_CODES_HEADER> genericRepositoryHeader,
    IGenericRepository<BATCHES> genericRepositoryBatches,
    IGenericRepository<LINES> genericRepositoryLine,
    IExternalCodesMapper externalCodesMapper,
    IExceptionLogHelper exceptionLogger)
{
    m_GenericRepositoryECodes = genericRepositoryECodes;
    m_GenericRepositoryHeader = genericRepositoryHeader;
    m_ExceptionLogger = exceptionLogger;
    m_GenericRepositoryBatches = genericRepositoryBatches;
    m_GenericRepositoryLine = genericRepositoryLine;
    m_ExternalCodesMapper = externalCodesMapper;
}
```

Not working `ApiController` constructor:

```
public AggregationsController(
    IGenericRepository<Data.AGGREGATIONS> repositoryAggs,
    IGenericRepository<Data.AGGREGATION_CHILDS> repositoryAggChilds,
    IGenericRepository<Data.CODES> repositoryCodes,
    IAggregationsMapper aggregationMapper,
    IAggregationChildsMapper aggChildsMapper,
    IExceptionLogHelper exceptionLogger)
{
    m_RepositoryAggs = repositoryAggs;
    m_RepositoryAggChilds = repositoryAggChilds;
    m_RepositoryCodes = repositoryCodes;
    m_AggregationMapper = aggregationMapper;
    m_AggChildsMapper = aggChildsMapper;
    m_ExceptionLogger = exceptionLogger;
}
public CodesController(
    IGenericRepository<CODES> repositoryCodes,
    ICodesMapper codesMapper,
    IExceptionLogHelper exceptionLogger)
{
    m_RepositoryCodes = repositoryCodes;
    m_CodesMapper = codesMapper;
    m_ExceptionLogger = exceptionLogger;
}
```

Any idea about this Poltergeist?

If you need something else, please tell me.

Comment: when are you getting this error?

Comment: I get this error when I do a POST to http://myServer/api/Codes.

Comment: does the working controller have a parameterless public constructor?

Comment: I presume you are injecting the dependencies via a DI framework? Are you sure everything is correctly registered in the container?

Comment: You're missing a required dependency (not registered) and ninject is cascading to a parameterless constructor which does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a required dependency (not registered) and ninject is cascading to a parameterless constructor which does not exist.

One way to determine which dependency is missing is to remove parameters from the constructor until you don't get this error.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have forgotten to register a dependency. Thanks!!